# Next.js using Firebase auth when fetching data in getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-security, server-side-rendering

I have a barebones rule in firebase

```
allow read: if request.auth != null;
```

I have a **react/Next.js** page that needs to read that data.

If I request the data from the component inside something like useEffect I get the data.

If I move the request to **getServerSideProps** I get

```
[FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.] {
   code: 'permission-denied',
   customData: undefined,
   toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

If I change the rule to `allow read: if true;` getServerSideProps can get the data.

I've installed the firebase admin SDK and am able to call verifyIdToken from getServerSideProps and use the console to see the info about the user.

Am I supposed to be adding the user's token, or id to the firebase request?

```
const compQuery = query(collection(firestore, "companies"));
const compSnapshot = await getDocs(compQuery);
```

or is there something else I have missed?
can I get rid of the firebase admin SDK?

Comment: You used firebase auth? You cannot use getServerSideprops to get the user data because it's server side, and server side do not have the user token.

Comment: You should probably only use those query on the client side because, in useEffect as that's how we usually do it. It's also more performant because data is cached inside indexDb

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you solved it? I've installed `firebaseAdmin` to verify the user token and later I use `firebase` to fetch the data, by following the security rules, but it keep showing the **permission denied error**.